# how to click second time on recycle view and firsr time data is show in android i use a flag but this not work any one can help me

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final MyportfolioRecycleview_Record record = dataList.get(position);

        for(int i=0;i< dataList.size();i++) {
                holder.issuerNameInBoldLetters.setText(record.getIssuerNameInBoldLetters());
                holder.issuerNameInNormalLetters.setText(record.getIssuerNameInNormalLetters());
                holder.bondCoupon.setText(record.getBondCoupon() + "%");
                holder.bondMaturityDate.setText(record.getBondMaturityDate());
                holder.currency.setText(record.getCurrency());
                holder.totalBondPrice.setText(record.getTotalBondPrice());
                holder.bondPrice.setText(record.getBondPrice());
                holder.priceChange.setText(record.getPriceChange());
                holder.pricename.setText(record.getPicename());
                holder.daychange.setText(record.getDaychange());
        }
        holder.layout2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(clicktime=true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "datachanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    updateData(dataList1);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    clicktime=false;
                }
                if(clicktime=false){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "datachanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    updateData1(dataList);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    clicktime=true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.layout2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /* if(clicktime=true)*/ if(clicktime==true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "datachanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    updateData(dataList1);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    clicktime=false;
                }
                /*  if(clicktime=false)*/ if(clicktime==false){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "datachanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    updateData1(dataList);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    clicktime=true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To check equivalency in Java, you need to use double equals. Or, you can just put if(clicktime) for true
if(!clicktime) for false

Comment: plese expalin am not understand properly

Comment: @ParveenSharma Check the answer below this one. They fixed your code.